# async middleware gets skipped and next route gets executed in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, middleware

I'm trying to implement a zotero-like app using express.js and I've got a problem.

I actually don't know exactly what the problem is, but based on the logs I get, I understood that somehow my middlewares don't execute in the order they are set and also the request leaks into another route handler I've set for errors.

this is my route handler for Collections:

```js
router
    .route('/')
    .post(
        controller.addLibraryToBody,
        controller.validateBody.create,
        controller.createOne,
        controller.sendResponse('create'),
        controller.debugLog
    );
```

these are the middlewares:

```js
// in the parent Controller class
moveReqKeyToBody(bodyKey: string, ...nestedReqKey: string[]) {
        return function (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            let iterator: any = req;
            nestedReqKey.forEach(key => {
                if (iterator[key]) iterator = iterator[key];
                else
                    next(createError(400, `missing item from request: ${nestedReqKey}`));
            });
            req.body[bodyKey] = iterator;

            next();
        };
    }

preventMaliciousBody(bodyValidationKeys: BodyValidationKeys) {
        let { mandatory = [], allowed = [] } = bodyValidationKeys;

        return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            allowed = allowed.concat(mandatory);
            if (
                mandatory.every(value => req.body[value]) &&
                Object.keys(req.body).every(value => allowed.includes(value))
            )
                next();
            else next(createError(400, 'invalid body'));
        };
    }

createOne = catchAsync(
        async (
            req: IRemoveFieldsRequest,
            res: Response,
            next: NextFunction
        ): Promise<void> => {
            const document = await this.model.create(req.body);
            if (req.removeFields) {
                req.removeFields.forEach(field => {
                    document[field] = undefined;
                });
            }

            req[this.modelName] = document;

            next();
        }
    );


sendResponse = (operation: CRUD) => {
        return (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            switch (operation) {
                case 'create':
                    res.status(201).json({
                        status: 'success',
                        data: req[this.modelName]
                    });
                    break;
            }
        };
    };


debugLog(req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        console.log(
            `${Date.now()} - ${req.url} - ParamKeys: ${Object.keys(
                req.params
            )} - BodyKeys: ${Object.keys(req.body)}`
        );
        next();
    }


// in the CollectionController
addLibraryToBody = this.moveReqKeyToBody('parent', 'library', 'id');



validateBody = {
        create: catchAsync(
            async (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
                if (!req.body.type) req.body.type = collectionTypes.collection;
                this.preventMaliciousBody(this.bodyKeys.create)(req, res, next);

                if (
                    req.body.type === collectionTypes.searchingCollection &&
                    !req.body.searchQuery
                )
                    next(createError(400, 'invalid body'));
                else next();
            }
        )
}
```

and this is my app.js:

```js
app
    .use('/api', apiRouter)
    .use(
        '*',
        function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            // todo fix this weird bug
            if (res.headersSent) {
                console.log(req.url);
                console.log(req.body);
                console.log(req.params);
            } else next();
        },
        Controller.unavailable
    )
    .use(errorHandler);
```

this is postman's output on that route:

```
{
    "status": "success"
}
```

this is the server's cli output:
*I have morgan middleware running(first line)*

```
POST /api/libraries/6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668/collections 201 6.358 ms - 20
1683371139354 - / - ParamKeys: id - BodyKeys: name,parent,type
/
{
  name: 'norma coll',
  parent: '6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668',
  type: 'Collection'
}
{ '0': '/api/libraries/6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668/collections' }
```

I tried logging everything, and searched the web but didn't understand what's wrong.

---

EDIT: I added 2 `console.log`s to the `createOne` method:

```js
createOne = catchAsync(
        async (
            req: IRemoveFieldsRequest,
            res: Response,
            next: NextFunction
        ): Promise<void> => {
            console.log('started creating...');
            const document = await this.model.create(req.body);
            if (req.removeFields) {
                req.removeFields.forEach(field => {
                    document[field] = undefined;
                });
            }

            req[this.modelName] = document;
            console.log('created');

            next();
        }
    );
```

and it was printed before and after the morgan's log:

```
started creating...
POST /api/libraries/6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668/collections 201 23.049 ms - 20
created
1683387954094 - / - ParamKeys: id - BodyKeys: name,parent,type
/
{
  name: 'nor coll',
  parent: '6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668',
  type: 'Collection'
}
{ '0': '/api/libraries/6447a4c4dc088d6d43204668/collections' }
```

So I guess there's a problem here? maybe it doesn't get executed completely and therefore calls the next middlewares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main control problem is in `validateBody.create()`.  You are executing:

```
this.preventMaliciousBody(this.bodyKeys.create)(req, res, next);
```

But, assuming that it's synchronous as you continue executing right after it.  Instead, it isn't done until it calls `next()` internal to its implementation.  You can use nested middleware like this by sending your own callback for next instead of the actual next.  That way, you can see when it's actually done by when your callback gets called.

```
validateBody = {
    create: catchAsync(
        async (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            if (!req.body.type) req.body.type = collectionTypes.collection;
            this.preventMaliciousBody(this.bodyKeys.create)(req, res, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                    return;
                }
                if (
                    req.body.type === collectionTypes.searchingCollection &&
                    !req.body.searchQuery
                ) {
                    next(createError(400, 'invalid body'));
                } else {
                    next();
                }

            }));

        }
    )
}
```

---

There are also several coding errors in `moveReqKeyToBody()`.

Inside a `.forEach()`, you can call `next(createError(400, ...));` multiple times and then after the `.forEach()` loop, you then call `next()`.  You need to code it so that `next(...)` is only ever called once.

Though I can't really tell what this function is supposed to be doing or if this is entirely responsible for the problem you are asking about, you can start by fixing the above two issues like this:

```
// in the parent Controller class
moveReqKeyToBody(bodyKey: string, ...nestedReqKey: string[]) {
    return function (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        let iterator: any = req;
        for (let key: any of nestedReqKey) {
            if (iterator[key]) {
                iterator = iterator[key];
            } else {
                next(createError(400, `missing item from request: ${nestedReqKey}`));
                return;
            }
        }
        req.body[bodyKey] = iterator;

        next();
    };
}
```

---

I also notice that `sendResponse()` doesn't do anything if the switch operation is not `create`.  You should at least have a `default` arm to that switch that sends a response or triggers an error.   If you're always expecting the argument to be `create`, then you wouldn't even need the `switch` statement.  So, it should be one or the other.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not it. the `preventMaliciousBody` method is synchronous and doesn't have any problems in my other routes (it's in my parent controller class which is the parent class of all my other controllers). the `moveReqKeyToBody` doesn't throw any errors either. about the `sendResponse` method i deleted the other cases to make it easier to scan through my code.

Comment: I really don't know what happens that throws this error because all these methods work like a charm in other routes (except for the PATCH '/:id' route in the exact same router).

Comment: @Adjective - So why are you passing `next` to `this.preventMaliciousBody()` if you don't expect it to use it.  That's just a bad practice.  There's too much missing code/context for me to see anything more.  You can debug this yourself by inserting `console.log()` statements in multiple places in every middleware here and then track the exact execution order.

Comment: It's because i sometimes use it as an standalone middleware. but here i needed some logic around it so i did executed it in another middleware. Yeah I tried adding a `console.log` in my `createOne` method since it seemed like it didn't fill the `req[this.modelName]` and edited the problem with the result i got

Comment: @Adjective - Please show the code for `preventMaliciousBody()` then.  If you sometimes use it as a normal middleware, it must be calling `next()` then or sending a response.  Either way, your existing way of using it that I commented on is wrong.  MIddleware can't be used as middleware in one contexts and as a normal synchronous function in another context.  It has to be designed to be one or the other as they just work differently.

Comment: i used this syntax elsewhere too and it worked perfectly. either way here's the code in the question.

Comment: @Adjective - Yes, this problem I describe in my answer DOES exist in your implementation of `preventMaliciousBody()`.  You are calling `next()` from that.  So, your original code would cause route handling to continue separately from your other code which would precisely create the situation you describe.  You NEED my suggested fix here.  Perhaps that's not the ONLY problem your code has, but you need this fix first and then if there's still a problem, you can continue to debug other sources of whatever problem remains.

Comment: I'm gonna try that. But why does it only happen here and not in for example in my signup route? (it uses mostly the same parent methods and logic)

Comment: it worked! thank you. but i don't understand why i don't get the same problem in some other routes? and the better solution would be to make it a normal method (not a middleware) and wrap it in a middleware if needed, right?

Comment: @Adjective - You'd have to show me the code for your signup route to see why it works there.  Middleware is JUST a function that follows a specific calling suggestion.  You can either pass it the real `next()` handler if you want it to continue routing and not execute your own code when its done OR you can pass it your own `next()` handler like I've done here so you know when it's done and you can then execute some of your code before you either send a response yourself or continue routing by calling the real `next()`.

Comment: @Adjective - If you're using the function as actually middleware, then its design is fine.  If you're not actually using it as plain middleware, then a generic function that returns a promise would likely be easier to use everywhere.  But, if you are using it as plain middleware, then this approach works fine for the few places it isn't being used a pure middleware.